# ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm trying to insert a column in oracle which is in "TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE" format.

Below is the insert SQL:

```
INSERT INTO print_temp 
( print_before_tswtz ) 
VALUES 
( 
  TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY -  INTERVAL '1' SECOND ) 
  +   
  NUMTODSINTERVAL('5','DAY') 
) ;
```

Below is the error which I get; 
 Error report:

> SQL Error: ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format
>    01840. 00000 -  "input value not long enough for date format"

Could anyone please help me with this error? Thanks!

Comment: Paste `ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format 01840. 00000 - "input value not long enough for date format"` into your favorite search engine. Bang! Answers.

Answer (score 0):

Timestamp keep's parts of second, so you can use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO print_temp ( print_before_tswtz ) VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ( TRUNC(SYSDATE) + INTERVAL '1' DAY - INTERVAL '1' SECOND||'.000000000' ) +
NUMTODSINTERVAL('5','DAY') ) ;
```